# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: iis, shared-hosting, godaddy, asp.net-mvc, web.config

```
Line 54:             <providers>
Line 55:                 <clear/>
Line 56:                 <add name="RolesProvider" type="Eacademy.Library.Membership.CustomRoleProvider, Eacademy" />
Line 57:             </providers>
Line 58:         </roleManager>
```

error on line 56 on IIS7 server GoDaddy. shared host at medium trust. I am uploading an ASP.NET MVC website. This works on my local machine.

here is the error `http://aivan.info/`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set "Copy Local" in Visual Studio on the Eacademy assembly? (Right click on the Assembly in Visual Studio and see the property "Copy Local" - prob needs to be True here since the Eacademy stuff is prob not already on GoDaddy.)